# iPhone:Image API in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image

Is there any Image API available in iPhone?? so using that API I can develop a functionality to get all information of that photo in iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the **ImageIO** framework

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462

Answer (score 1):

yes, since IOS4 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html

depending on what you want exactly, this deals with the camera output.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very fuzzy: please make it more exact.

if you want to get information about the size of the image, orientation, type etc, you can use the UIImage and CGImage classes which will give you information about the image itself. (size, colors, pixel size etc)..

If you want to get or access pictures in the Photos app of the iphONE, ALAssetsLibrary is what you need to read about - you can save and get images and videos from the iPhone's native album.

If you want the metadata saved alongside each image - like the location it picture was taken, the lens size, date taken etc.. - I am unsure how one gets that data.